# Why should a type T to be emplaced at the end of a vector required to be move constructible?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, stdvector, move-semantics

Why shouldn't a public constructor (and destructor) suffice for an object of type `T` to be emplaced at the back of a vector? The following snippet is ill-formed.

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
  Foo() {}
  Foo(int) {}
  ~Foo() {}

  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Foo> vfoo(10);

  vfoo.emplace_back();
}
```

The `emplace_back` requires that `Foo` at least be move constructible, and this code fails to compile because the move constructor is deleted along with the copy constructor. But I imagined `emplace_back` to call the default constructor using placement new.

Comment: What would you expect to happen when the container was resized and the existing contents needed to be copied?

Comment: See "Type requirements" under "Parameters" on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace

Comment: @o11c `emplace` and `emplace_back` are different things, and in any event the question is why there is such a requirement, not what the requirement is.

Comment: because this is how it was defined. easy as this.

Comment: @DavidHaim. yes. The question was about the rationale for doing so.

Answer (score 7):

The vector is constructed with `10` elements in your example.

Then you add one.  If there is no more room in `capacity()`, a new buffer must be allocated, the 10 elements already there must be moved into it, then your new element appended.

You'll notice the word `move` above -- that is why you need the move ctor.

What more, even if you did not have elements there, or you carefully ensured that there was enough capacity, the compiler cannot know that: the code to move existing elements will be compiled (if not run) and you will get your error.

A "push back, and I guarantee there was already capacity" method is missing from `vector`.  That, plus a "set capacity, discard any existing elements" would let you add elements without requiring a move ctor (or copy ctor fallback).  Until `emplace` was invented, all add elements required a copy or move: and until C++11 all add elements required a copy.  The lack of these two methods with strange semantics simply to permit a unmovable type to have limited use of a `vector` is not that strange.

I encourage you to write a container that has those two extensions (or something similar) and propose adding it to C++: it might also help in high performance use cases (compilers are meh at proving that I did ensure the capacity was sufficient in my experience).

Comment: Would it be possible to remove the Moveable requirements, and make `emplace_back` throw if the object is not moveable but a reallocation is required?  (or use a differently-named new emplace function if we don't want to change that one)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Definitely need separate functions. It's impossible to accurately detect whether something is `MoveInsertable`, as far as I know.

Comment: @T.C. But you can precisely detect it (but the fact that moving actually moves cannot be determined, but not enforcing that seems reasonable?)  Or is there something more?  (I guess allocators that fail late?)

Comment: @Yakk How do you detect it in ordinary code (without an intrinsic)? Sure, you can detect whether `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, rv)` is well-formed in the immediate context, but that doesn't mean anything, because it is the moving inside that call that's actually going to break. And then, there are things whose move will fail in overload resolution (move ctor deleted or nonexistent) and things whose move constructor will pretend to exist and then fail to instantiate, and you can only detect the former.